# Deformations and blow-down

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

I would like to understand how blowing down affects (first order) deformations.

For a concrete example, set $D=k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ and consider in $\mathbb{A}^2_D=\operatorname{Spec} D[x,y]$ the following deformation of the two coordinate axis and the line $y=1$:

$$X=\operatorname{Spec} D[x,y]/(xy-a\epsilon)\cap(x(y-1)-b\epsilon)$$ for $a,b\in k$.

Now blow down the $y$-axis. In other words, consider the map to $\text k[u,v]/(uv)$ given by $$(t,0)\mapsto (t,0), (t,1)\mapsto (0,t), (0,t)\mapsto (0,0)$$ which, if I am correct, should be given by $$u\mapsto x(y-1),v\mapsto xy$$ (or maybe the other way around, doesn't matter).

Now it is clear that $uv-\epsilon(au+bv)$ (again, maybe I switched $a$ and $b$) maps to $0$, so the structure at the node is $$D[u,v]/(uv-\epsilon(au+bv))$$ whose completion is $D[[u,v]]/(uv)$ (only constant term matters, and here it is $0$), so it is a trivial deformation.

I would have expected something like $D[[u,v]]/(uv-\epsilon(a+b))$... what did I do wrong? Do really all deformations blow down to the trivial one?

Note: I carried out the same computation in the case of the disjoint union of two nodes mapping to a node collapsing one component from each node. The result seems to still be the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are doing. Exactly what are you deforming? The union of the lines $x=0, y=0, y=1$? In that case, I'm not sure if this is a flat deformation. So if I understand correctly, you want to understand the induced deformation (if it is still flat...) after having blown down the embedding space?

Comment: After having blown down the $y$ axis. I think everything is flat here, hope I didn't get it wrong!